# electronic signature c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a web application based on C#,asp.net.

In application i generate an xml file that contents journal records. 
Admin user must sign this xml file with his usb token.

In windows application i can read usb token certificate file and i can sign the xml file.

But in web application i execute the same code and i get an this error:
"Card inserted card reader not found".

How can i access on client usb token and certificate from ny web application?

Is there anyone using electronic signature on web application?

Comment: Upload the certificate maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution. You have to create ActiveX control or Java applet and install it on client machine. That is how my internet banking works.

Answer (score -1):

The usual and the easiest way is to let the users upload a scanned copy of their signatures. The application should then save it somewhere (database or some folder on the server). Whenever required, these users should be able to use their signatures. It then automatically becomes electronic signature. Just properly authenticate and authorize users before letting them use the electronic signatures.

Hope this helps!!